# Can't record more than one wave with pyaudio (no default output device)

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm trying to write the most simple program to take two recordings and record two wave files. You can get the raw code: https://gist.github.com/579095ac89fa2fff58db

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def record(file_name):

  stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input = True,
    frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

  frames = []
  print "starting recording " + file_name + "."
  for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * 2)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
  print "finished recording"

  stream.stop_stream()
  stream.close()
  p.terminate()

  wf = wave.open(file_name, 'wb')
  wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
  wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
  wf.setframerate(RATE)
  wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
  wf.close()

record('first.wav')
# try again
record('second.wav')
```

Everything works fine if I only call the record function once, but if I try to call it again, I get: IOError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device).

```
python record2x.py
starting recording first.wav.
finished recording
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "record2x.py", line 38, in <module>
    record('second')
  File "record2x.py", line 16, in record
    frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing odd. You called `p.terminate()` in your function meaning that you dismissed PyAudio completely. So It detached from audio cards and awaits new initialization.
`p.terminate()` call only upon exiting of your program.
Also, here, in your function, `stream.stop_stream()` is unnecessary as `stream.close()` will do the trick. Unless you experience some clickings when starting some audio later, but this may only be when using `output=True`, not `input=True`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was terminating the stream prematurely. I just needed to remove the terminate call.

Comment: Not the stream, whole PyAudio system. Streams you may open and close as many as you want and whenever you want.